# An object of ApiController for each request ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

Will a new object of API Controller creating after each request to the page?

So I need to know if condition #1 is always true or not?

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController {
    private int _reqState = -1;

    public object Get(int id) {
        if (_reqState == -1}  {} //condition #1
        //DO SOME WORK WITH _reqState
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a controller has a short lifetime, just for this request. After that it is disposed and your value is lost.

If you want to keep some state, you have to use `Session`, `Application` or an external storage to save your state.

For example:

```
private int ReqState
{
    get
    {
        return (this.HttpContext.Session["ReqState"] as int?).GetValueOrDefault(-1);
    }
    set
    {
        this.HttpContext.Session["ReqState"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ya, I just wanna know that there are guarantees that an object for each request will created, but I cannot find it in MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value of `_reqState` is not changed between the invocation of your Action method (`Get()`) and then conditional check, or in your controller constructor - then yes the condition is always true.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController {

    public ProductsController()
    {
        // As long as _reqState is not changed here
    } 

    private int _reqState = -1;

    public object Get(int id) {

        // ... or here

        if (_reqState == -1}  {} //condition #1 - always true
        //DO SOME WORK WITH _reqState
    }
}
```

The value set for `_reqState` is not carried across multiple requests as the controller is created and destroyed with each request.

So the value of `_reqState` is not the same instance of the variable each time, it's a newly set `-1` value.